# WebStorm Deployment menu options greyed out?

Tags: webstorm

I have decided to use WebStorm it seems good however most of the time if I go to `Tools - Deployment` the upper menu options are greyed out? I can configure and I can go to Options but I cannot download from the server? I can open the remote host just fine and scroll through documents that way but from what I understand WebStorm loses a lot of functionality if you develop this way.

I have no Git and am just working by myself so this workflow is fine for me right now.....if I can download from the server!

[image]

In my Deployment Menu from Tools all of the tests work and I can autofind my folder and all that. Whats going on?

Here is the Mappings section:

[image]

Comment: I do have one in Mappings  `Local path ..... is our of project.` What does that mean?

Comment: I posted the picture of the page. The Local path and Server path are correct. Im not sure whats going on. ..

Comment: I created that file folder so is it looking for a config file or something?

Comment: Ok so I changed that back, which is fine because I can over-write that locally. Now the error is gone but still no download option?

Comment: Yes it works like a champ.

Comment: Well its not showing the things so its not the actual answer to the question. I mean the "Test Connection" button is working fine. I still cannot download from server.

Comment: I went back to look at it again and I was able to see the options! However when I selected "Download from Server" it said "Nothing was found to download" which is odd. Now the options are gone again! Lovely.
So post your answer I'll mark it. However does it not show if it thinks it has already sync'd? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Yes its highlighted. I even unhighlighted it and tried it, then highlighted it and tried it and same thing. This is very frustrating! Why do they have to make this such a pain.

Comment: Ah! I just figured out that part. After I input the path in the server on the Mappings page I have to enter `/` as the root path. I did that and it allowed me to download files!

Comment: So put that in your answer as well.

Comment: as told: remove your comments - it looks strange :s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Local path` has to be part of your current project (root or a subfolder).

The deployment path a folder of your server where it should be stored - if it should be stored on the root it is just a slash: '/'.
If your connection is successful you should be able to select a folder with the dialog (on the right).

Make also sure your server is marked as 'default' which is your default connection for this project - [based on that link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/uploading-and-downloading-files.html#d454170e299).

The projects has been indexed by WebStorm so you can easily refactor and *other fancy stuff*.
Every project has a root folder with a config folder `.idea`.

Comment: I think mentioning that the RootPath in the Connections Tab of Deployment needs to be `/`, also that you can make a default connection.

Answer (score 1):

For those that are convinced their mappings are set up the right way, here's one key thing to check.  It seems like their SFTP usage does not follow symbolic links (on the remote) correctly.  And you can see that if you go to the Mappings tab and click on the "..." for the Deployment path - when it shows the list, symlinked dirs do not show up.  By avoiding symlinks in the path, I was able to get the upper part of the Tools/Deployment menu to be active again (non-grey)

I was using PyCharm Pro 2017.3